# Rerun original function upon completion of another function in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm still trying to master jQuery, AJAX, and JSON.

On my application, I have the following dropdown select menu:

```
 <select id="serviceload" name="serviceload"></select>
```

I auto populate the OPTIONS with another function which I don't think is necessary to display here.  Just know that the above SELECT has 1 or more OPTION values.

This is followed by the content section:

```
 <div class="row" id="completeProfile">
    // series of DIVS and TABLES
 </div>
```

Initially, the content section is hidden, so the user will only see the dropdown menu:

```
 $('#completeProfile').hide();
```

And now, the jQuery: this next piece of code is what I use when the user chooses a selection from the dropdown menu.  Every time they pick a new selection, queries rerun, and new content is displayed to the screen, unless they select a blank OPTION.

```
 $('#serviceload').change(function () {
     var page = $('#serviceload').val();
     if (page == "") {
         $('#completeProfile').hide();
     } else {
         $.post('api/profileSearch.php', {
             page: page
         }, function (data) {
             var obj = JSON.parse(data);
             $('#portBody').empty();
             var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item) {
                 return '<tr><td>' + item.PORT + '</td><td>' + item.NAME + '</tr>';
             });
             $('#portBody').html(htmlToInsert);
         });

         // I do several more $.post to return data into specific tables
         // Take note of this next $.post

         $.post('api/vesselSearch.php', {
             page: page
         }, function (data) {
             var obj = JSON.parse(data);
             $('#vesselinfo').empty();
             var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item) {
                 return '<tr><td><a href="#" class="editVesselLink" data-toggle="modal" data-vessel="' + item.VESSEL_NAME + '">Edit</a></td><td>' + item.VESSEL_NAME + '</td></tr>';
             });
         });

         // after all the queries are ran, and the data is returned, now we show the content
         $('#completeProfile').show();
     }
 });
```

In the vesselInfo portion above, there is section that prints a hyperlink with which you can click, and it opens a modal window.  This is for editing purpose.  This functions properly.

Here is where the issue lies.

Back in the content section, there is another hyperlink that opens a modal window to add a new vessel.

```
 <h3>Vessels</h3> / <a href="#" id="vesselInfoLink" data-toggle="modal">Add New</a>
```

This opens an Add New Vessel modal.  In that modal there is a FORM with a button that reads like this:

```
 <button type="button" id="addVesselSubmit">Add</button>
```

When this button is clicked, it sends the values entered by the user to a PHP script which updates a table.

```
$('#addVesselSubmit').click(function () {
    var addservice = $('#addservice').val();
    var addvessel = $('#addvessel').val();
    $.post('api/addInfo.php', {
        addservice: addservice,
        addvessel: addvessel
    }, function (data) {
        // here is where my problem lies
        if (data == 0) {
            alert("Vessel was not saved");
        } else {
            alert("Vessel was saved");
            // At this point, I need to rerun the main function above so that it shows the vessel that was added immediately to the content section without a page refresh
        }
    });
});
```

So in the code directly above, if the new record was successfully saved to the table, the whole content section should rerun without a page refresh, with the new record automatically showing in the vesselInfo section.

I think the code that is used to display the content needs to be turned into a main function that can be called when the addVesselSubmit is successful, but I am not sure how to proceed with that.

To reiterate my question: I need to be able to save a new record, and print the new record to the page without a page refresh.

Comment: _"JQUERY AJAX rerun original function upon completion of another function"_ ? What is "original function" ? Which is "another function" ?

Comment: Are you trying to rerun `$('#addVesselSubmit').click()` ?

Comment: Apologies...I'm trying to rerun       $('#serviceload').change(function (){

Comment: Simply add `$('#serviceload').trigger('change')`

Comment: Wow............just wow.  Thank you so much, Rejith R Krishnan.  That did exactly what I wanted it to do.  Upvote to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('api/addInfo.php', {
    addservice: addservice,
    addvessel: addvessel
}, function (data) {
    // here is where my problem lies
    if (data == 0) {
        alert("Vessel was not saved");
    } else {
        alert("Vessel was saved");
        // At this point, I need to rerun the main function above so that it shows the vessel that was added immediately to the content section without a page refresh
        //Trigger a change on element
        $('#serviceload').trigger('change');
       /*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/            
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again.  This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.